# grails app layout horking on bootstrap-responsive.css

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, layout, groovy

I have a simple Grails application.  I did not author the front end, only the business logic layer.

I checked out all the source from SVN and the app starts, but I cannot load the main url.  It errors out with the messages below.  I have tried refreshing dependencies, but to no avail.

I have spelunked every file I could think of to try to fix this. What gets my attention is the FORWARD slash in front of the css, while the other delimiters in the path are backslashes.

Does anyone have any idea where this is going wrong and how to fix it?  Maybe the front end developer needs to check something in?

```
  Error 2013-07-31 13:50:24,036 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR [/MyClientAppName].[grails-errorhandler]  - Servlet.service() for servlet grails-errorhandler threw exception
Message: Error applying layout : main
    Line | Method
->> 1110 | runWorker in \grails-app\views\layouts\main.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    603 | run       in     ''
^    722 | run . . . in     ''
Caused by GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <r:layoutResources>: Module [bootstrap] depends on resource [/css\bootstrap\bootstrap-responsive.css] but the file cannot be found
->>  464 | runWorker in \grails-app\views\layouts\main.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <r:layoutResources>: Module [bootstrap] depends on resource [/css\bootstrap\bootstrap-responsive.css] but the file cannot be found
->>    8 | doCall    in C:/workspaces/GGTS1/MyClientAppName/grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: Module [bootstrap] depends on resource [/css\bootstrap\bootstrap-responsive.css] but the file cannot be found
->
```

Comment: What does `grails-app/conf/ApplicationResources.groovy` look like?

Comment: Does `web-app\css\bootstrap\bootstrap-responsive.css` exist in your checkout?